Discuss closure of "What does Nixpkgs' `callPackage` do?`
As per Mark Rotteveel's suggestion, re-posting my responses here regarding my question. (See archived page, in case comments have been deleted.)
The reasons below also support why this question should be opened: If my answer to my question is not adequate, people will have a shot to give better ones.

Response to criticism and detractors
Only addressing the comments, the closing of the question, and call
for deletion, not the downvotes. Why someone does the latter is their
prerogative. I'm no writing genius and some may dislike it, so the act
of downvote is justification in itself in my view.
"This question is far too broad"
callPackage is a complex function (reasons include the Nix language
being lazy, usage of fixed-point evaluation, overrides, etc.), and
this complexity steals the spotlight from what this function actually
does and why is it so useful, confusing newcomers and "returnees to
Nix" like myself in the process.
This thread is borne out of the fact that I couldn't find a simple,
concise summary of its behaviour, and my approach works for me (i.e.,
present the same answer multiple times with increasing levels of
detail). Plus, this site is for sharing such insights, so someone else
might find it useful.
If you still find question too broad, please do the courtesy of
justify your reasoning. Thank you.
"This question is off-topic"
This is a question about one of the most important core standard
library functions of Nixpkgs (the largest open source package
repository right now), and it is written using the Nix programming
language, so this is a programming question.
The Nix ecosystem has a large number of command line tools,
callPackage is not one of them, so it's on topic. I refer to such a
tool in my answer (namely, nix repl), but it is only provided as aid
to interpret the code snippets.
Please justify how this is off-topic.
"Self-answers are welcome here."
And yet, it feels like they aren't. I read the linked article, which
is what encouraged me to write such threads, and I couldn't find any
part in there saying that this thread violates any rules.



"And yet, it feels like they aren't" - like you've already been told on main, self-answers are welcome, but the question they're posted to needs to be a good question. You're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for that bit. The act of self-answering is fine; but the question is still bad, regardless of whether you provided a self-answer or not. Self-answering is not a get out of jail free-card for all the other asking rules.

“This is a question about one of the most important core standard library functions of Nixpkgs” - This isn’t relevant, nor a reason to keep your question open. Just like “Plus, this site is for sharing such insights, so someone else might find it useful.”, isn’t a reason to keep it open either

First, thank you for moving the meta-commentary here. However, that was not really a "suggestion"; meta content like this has no place in questions or answers, as an elementary principle of the site. You have been around for over 12 years now, so you should understand by now how this works. If not, please take a moment to read through the Help Center, especially What is "meta"? How does it work?, and take the site tour. Community standards do change over time, in some ways.

"Self-answers are welcome here." And yet, it feels like they aren't. I read the linked article, which is what encouraged me to write such threads, and I couldn't find any part in there saying that this thread violates any rules.

You should also have read the rest of Chris' comment:

the question you ask must still be on-topic. This one is far too broad. Please revisit the tour and review what is on-topic in the help center. SO is for specific, focused questions, not how-tos. This isn't a blogging platform.

"Blog article" is the exact same first impression I got of your question and answer before looking at any comments.
However, I think Chris mis-spoke in two places.
First, the question is clearly not off topic. Many people lazily say "off-topic" to mean "should be closed, in accordance with the standard closure reasons, but of course that's inaccurate. The question was closed as "Needs More Focus" (which it very clearly does), and as far as I can tell, all close votes selected that reason. I don't think that this was actually intended to mean "the question isn't about programming as defined in the Help Center, and I don't think anyone else here thought so, either.
Second, tons of successful questions ask how to do something. But the point is, they ask how to do one, specific, clearly defined thing, which does not obviously break down into a series of logical steps (which would make separate questions). Aside from that, it doesn't seem like your intent was to explain how to do something, but the reverse - what can be done with a thing.

That said:

callPackage is a complex function (reasons include the Nix language being lazy, usage of fixed-point evaluation, overrides, etc.), and this complexity steals the spotlight from what this function actually does and why is it so useful, confusing newcomers and "returnees to Nix" like myself in the process.

This is a restatement of the problem, not a rebuttal.
It's fantastic that you've identified what you think is an underappreciated tool and want to help people understand it better. But Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, which is not a place for exploring the potential of a tool all at once. it's a place for answering questions.
And "What does X do?" is only an appropriately scoped question when X does exactly one thing. Even then, it's better asked and answered the other way around: "How do I do (the thing that X does)?" Why? Because a) that avoids overlap with traditional reference documentation (and complements it instead); b) using questions to introduce that kind of reference feels very artificial.
If callPackage does many things that people might want to know how to do, then that implies the existence of many "how do I... ?" questions that can be answered with a specific application of callPackage. Please ask and answer those, instead, separately. Not only do you fit the format better, but you get multiple chances at well-received questions and answers.
An overview of the sort that you're trying to write simply doesn't make sense in Q&A format. The golden rule is that self-answered questions are judged the same way as any other questions, in terms of scope, clarity etc. Imagine if you weren't going to write your own answer, and you encountered a question like this from someone else. Would you have any idea what to say that would be helpful, especially after seeing that OP apparently consulted all these other references and is still confused, but can't coherently state what still needs to be explained? Does "please summarize these other links for me" sound like a question to you?

'And "What does X do?" is only an appropriately scoped question when X does exactly one thing.' - disagree. Or, with more nuance: I mostly agree if X does "many things" in the sense of having many different modes of operation controlled by parameters, but disagree strongly if X does "many things" in the sense that it always does many things whenever you invoke it. Understanding fully what such a multi-step X will actually do is often fundamental to being able to competently & correctly use it. Answers to how-to questions are unlikely to answer this in full, even if they use X.
